# Is it a good idea from a security standpoint to disable Referer headers in the browser? What discomforts will you have to deal with?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, referer

So what kind of discomfort will you have to deal with?

Will it break websites?

Or is it just a win for privacy?

You can disable the Referer headers in Firefox like this:

```
    Open Firefox and type “about:config” in the address bar and press “Enter“.
    If prompted with a warning, select “I accept the risk!“
    Find the entry that says “network.http.sendRefererHeader” and double-click on it.
    Set the entry to one of the following as desired:
  0 – Disable referrer.
```

---

Other options are:

```
    1 – Send the Referer header when clicking on a link, and set document.referrer for the following page.
    2 – Send the Referer header when clicking on a link or loading an image.
```

According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135653/how-does-sending-referrer-http-headers-protect-against-csrf-attacks) question the Referer headers can't be spoofed and sometimes may break anti-CSRF measures.

Comment: Try it- some websites will certainly be broken. What security benefits do you want to gain?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Mainly privacy if that's possible from not sending your Referer.